# in plotly, is there really no way to force a legend not to overlap the plot?

Tags: python, plotly

In my example, I need to render a plot with a legend that could have as many or as few entries as the user needs. I would like to anchor the legend below the plot as so:

`fig.update_layout(legend=dict(orientation='h', yanchor="bottom", y=-0.2, xanchor="center", x=0.5, font=dict(size=10))))`

But the problem is that when the legend ends up spreading over multiple rows, it obscures part of the plot. It seems that the `y=-0.2` bit applies to the middle of the legend, not the top of it. Is there a way to change this behaviour so the legend always starts at y=-0.2 below?

I found this similar question, which seems to suggest that there isn't:
[Is there a way to prevent the legend on plotly from moving up into the chart when its orientation is horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203229/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-legend-on-plotly-from-moving-up-into-the-chart-whe)

Comment: it wouldn't be very elegant, but you could attempt to approximate or calculate the number of rows the legend will be based on the number of entries and number of characters in each entry. and then dynamically set the y parameter based on that

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the y parameter in the legend dictionary sets the y coordinate in the middle rather than the top. Workarounds I can think of are manual - setting a fixed height or calculating the height for the plot and adjusting the y value accordingly.

Comment: the problem is that I'm not sure there's a reliable way of knowing how many rows the legend's going to be, because the number of entries and names can all change. If I knew the number of rows I could adjust y.

Answer (score 0):

They added absolute positioning of the legend with parameters `yref='container'` and `xref='container'`.

Use it with `automargin = True` for the `xaxis` and horizontal legend won't interfere with long tick labels.

I use this configuration for plotly.js in production:

```js
  legend: {
    y: 0,
    orientation: "h",
    yanchor: "bottom",
    yref: "container"
  },
  xaxis: {
    automargin: true
  }
}
```